# Adicionar valores em uma matriz de 3 dimensões

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, matriz

Como eu faço para que o usuário adicione valores à uma matriz [][][]?

```
calendarioEventos = new Evento[dia][mes][hora];
    for(int i = 0; i < calendarioEventos.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < calendarioEventos[i].length; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < calendarioEventos[i][j].length; k++) {
                this.calendarioEventos[i][j][k] = new Evento();
```

Eu tenho essa matriz de um calendário de eventos em que o usuário tem que adicionar um evento para um horário do dia. Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Passe as posições e seja feliz, agora, cade o seu código para ter uma resposta mais próxima a sua realidade?

Comment: Olá, poderia marcar a resposta como correta? Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[][][] matriz = new int[2][2][2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            System.out.println("Digite o valor para Matriz[" + i + "][" + j + "][" + k + "]");
            int val = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            matriz[i][j][k] = val;
        }
    }
}
```